# .gitignore not appearing in VScode's file explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitignore

In the standard Windows Explorer, the repo contains all the expected files: [A snip of my file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl3Rg.png).

In VSCode, the `.gitignore` [file does not display in the explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpUAN.png). It's still seemingly functional (all files in the `.gitignore` are ignored), but it poses an annoyance. Most notably, the `.gitignore` file *does* appear in [other repos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jKM3.png) that I have on my machine.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Check in your project folder `.vscode/settings.json`.

In section `files.exclude` most likely you will see the line

`"**/.gitignore":true`

Comment out or delete it and the file will appear in Visual Code Explorer

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of settings related to this, VS Code is pretty flexible and powerful here.

1. open `command palette` (shift-cmd-p on mac, or just type > in the regular file explorer)
2. search `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings`
3. search `gitignore`
4. uncheck `Use Ignore Files`

There are lots of other interesting settings to fiddle with there too.  Your changes will then be reflected in `[your project folder]/.vscode/settings.json`